# Difference between three and four digit file permissions?

Tags: bash, permissions, files

I was recently wondering what is the difference between three and four digit numerical file permissions. I obtain the numerical permissions by running `stat --format "%a" $file_name`.What is the difference between 0644 and 644?

Comment: Related: [Why do octal permissions start with 40?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/423675/why-do-octal-permissions-start-with-40)

Comment: I was wondering the difference between four and three digit file permissions...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The first digit in a four-digit permission is the sum of **set user id**  (4), **set group id** (2) and **sticky** (1).  A three-digit permission is just like a four-digit permission with the first digit set to zero.  Thus:

- 0644 is exactly the same as 644.
- 1644 is like 644 but the sticky bit is also set
- 4644 is like 644 but the set user ID bit is also set.

#### Examples of uses for the fourth-digit permissions

If a file with set user ID is executed, then it is executed as if by the owner of the file rather than the user doing the executing.  Thus, for example, `/bin/mount` is commonly owned by root and has permissions 4755 where the 4 signifies that, even if executed by a normal user, it will run with the owner's (root's) privileges.

Setting group ID on a directory is useful for sharing files.

The sticky bit is used on directories like `/tmp` so that all users can create files but prevents non-owners from deleting other people's files.  Thus, the permissions of `/tmp` are typically 1777 where 1 signifies that the sticky bit is set.

#### Documentation

From `man chmod`:

> A numeric mode is from one to four octal digits (0-7), derived by adding up the bits with values 4, 2, and 1.  Omitted digits are
>   assumed to be leading zeros.  The  first
>    digit  selects  the set user ID (4) and set group ID (2) and restricted deletion or sticky (1) attributes.  The second digit
>   selects permissions for the user who owns the
>    file: read (4), write (2), and execute (1); the third selects permissions for other users in the file's group, with the same values;
>   and the fourth for other users not in
>    the file's group, with the same values.

Comment: 4715 does not work. The bash file runs and does not throw any error but it should do `rm -rf` and it is not executed. If I run it as root it works but if I run it as another user it does not..

Comment: @Čamo Yes, that's correct. Most flavors of Unix, including Linux, have disabled the Set User ID bit for shell scripts, such as bash files, because of security issues.  SUID will work, however, on compiled executables.