# Get all permission octals of files?

Tags: 22.04, stat

'stat -c "%a" foo.bar' shows the three octal permissions of owner, group, and other.
How can I show the fourth for setuid, setgid, and sticky bit?

Comment: Did you actually try it on such a file, for example `stat -c '%a' /usr/bin/sudo` ?

Comment: ... see also [Difference between three and four digit file permissions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/976168/difference-between-three-and-four-digit-file-permissions)

Comment: If `%a` doesn't print the initial digit, it'scall `0`, none of the bits is set.

Comment: ... GNU stat accepts printf-style padding modifiers, so `stat -c '%04a'` will print a leading zero in that instance

Comment: Ah, no. Completely missed that! Thank you for your quick response, and expanding to all print all four.